# Windows Phone 7.1 RC and MVVM Light project templates out of the box dont work together. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, windows-phone-7.1

I have an existing Windows Phone 7.0 RTM app that was created using the MVVM Light project templates. After upgrading the app to Windows Phone 7.1 RC, I cannot preview the app in the emulator. The emulator appears to attempt to load and closes with the following error:

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I like MVVM light. I think it makes building the UI faster. At the same time I would like to use Windows Phone 7.1 RC because from what I understand it can connect to my WCF Data Service easily (without a 3rd party component e.g. http://odata.codeplex.com/releases/view/54698)

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Light works well on WP7.1 SDK but you should upgrade the MVVM Light libraries in your app.

As you've already got an app that works on WP7.0, the easiest way to get hold of these is probably to get the MvvmLightLibs project from NuGet [(Link here).](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvvmLightLibs)

I'm not 100% sure this will fix your issue, but I'm fairly confident. You might also need to remove the old MVVM Light binaries to get your app to run properly...

Comment: i had this exact same issue, and it was what paul says. the interactivity.dll was causing the issue in my case.